# In what state is an external hard drive if it is seen by OS but content is unreachable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I have an USB external hard drive. If I connect it to my computer which is run under Ubuntu, I can see a new folder corresponding to the hard drive (in both terminal and in the directories browser). However, if I click on the directory in the directories browser, it tries to open the folder and is unable to do that. The same happens if I `cd` to the harder drive folder in the terminal (I can do it) but if I executed `ls` being in the hard drive folder, the command does not return anything (and I cannot terminate the command by `Ctrl+C`). So, it looks like my hard drive has huge number of files but it is not the case.

So, my question is: How one can interpret this behavior? In what state is my hard drive? It is clear that it is some how damaged but can one say more about its state? For example would it be "completely" damaged, I think I would be unable to see the hard drive folder.

Another question related: Can I damage the hard drive more just by trying to enter in its folder and trying to list the files located there? I know that I cannot damage the hard drive in this way if it is in the normal (functioning case) but what if it damaged somehow? Can I damage the hard drive by breaking the `ls` command or by disconnecting it from my compute while the `ls` command still running there?

Comment: Is it making any grinding/scraping/screeching noises? If not then corrupted partition or file table perhaps. Interrupting `ls` shouldn't cause any more problems IMO but you should look to recover your data first of all to another drive before experimenting with it further.

Comment: @Karan, how can I do this "recover"? What should I do to recover?

Comment: I'd start with TestDisk and see what it can detect, but there are no end to the data recovery solutions available, both free and otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Some more troubleshooting questions for you:

Is the drive visible in output of fdisk -l ? If yes, what does it tell about the partition on that drive?

Can you mount the partition without problems?

Can you read the drive? You can test it using the dd command like this (use the correct if parameter - you should be able to determine that from fdisk -l output):

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null bs=16M
```

If this command runs fine, that means you are able to read every single byte from that drive. After that you can start playing around with mount options.